# AWS all annotations not applied

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubectl, amazon-elb

I am using a yaml config to create a network load balancer in AWS using kubectl.
The load balancer is created successfully and the target groups are attached correctly.

As the part of settings, I have passed annotations required for AWS, but all annotations are not applied when looking at the Load Balancer in aws console.

The name is not getting set and the load balancer logs are not enabled. I get a load balancer with random alphanumeric name.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-nlb-service
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: test-nlb # not set
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:***********:certificate/*********************
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp,http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: 443,8883
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags: "environment=dev,app=test, name=test-nlb-dev"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-enabled: "true" # not set
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-emit-interval: "15" # not set
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-s3-bucket-name: "random-bucket-name" # not set
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-s3-bucket-prefix: "random-bucket-name/dev/test-nlb-dev" # not set
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  ports:
    - name: mqtt
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: websocket
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8883
      targetPort: 1883
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: test
```

If anyone can point what could be the issue here ? I am using kubectl v1.19 and Kubernetes v1.19

Comment: What kubernetes version?

Comment: @whites11 v1.19

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a version problem.
I assume you are running the in-tree cloud controller and not an external one (see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/cloudprovider#deprecation-notice)).

The annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name` is not present even in the [master branch](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers/aws/aws.go) of kubernetes.

That does not explain why the other annotations do not work though. In fact
[here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.19.12/staging/src/k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers/aws/aws.go#L105) you can see what annotations are supported by kubernetes 1.19.12 and the others you mentioned are not working are listed in the sources.

You might find more information in the `controller-manager` logs.

My suggestion is to disable the in-tree cloud controller in `controller manager` and run the [standalone version](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Kubernetes Controllers that touch annotations of the form
`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-*`

One is built into kubernetes `aws-cloud-controller-manager`
(and runs on the EKS masters, so you can't see it.)

The other is a kubernetes add-on called `aws-load-balancer-controller`
(If you don't have this installed they'll be ignored, so basically if you install it per https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/deploy/installation/ your issue should be resolved.)

https://www.doit.com/demystifying-the-kubernetes-aws-lb-controller/
Explains the topic in depth, should be a good resource.
(disclaimer: I am the author of the linked article. Also fun fact, this and a few other posts inspired me to write it.)

Comment: Yeah had followed this, though great article!